# how can I dynamically assign an index to ng-show values in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Why doesn't this work?**

```
<div ng-repeat="report in reports track by $index">
    <div ng-model="myDiv{{ $index }}" ng-show="myDiv{{ $index }}">{{ report }} {{ index }}</div>
</div>
```

**Like this does?**

```
<div ng-repeat="report in reports track by $index">
    <div id="myDiv{{ $index }}"  name="myDiv{{ $index }}">{{ report }} {{ index }}</div>
</div>
```

While you can add $index to any name or id (renders as *id="myDiv1"*), it does not behave the same for other directives (will render as *ng-model="myDiv{{ $index }}"*).

My goal is to create a table where users can view, sort and download 6-10 different reports within a date range. The client requires a sortable list of reports all at once on the page, each with its own date-range-picker. Because the reports selection varies on the user, this needs to be done dynamically. The following is basically what I am trying to do...

```
<tr ng-repeat="report in reports track by $index">
    <td><p>{{ report.title }}</p></td>
    <td>
        <div id="dateRangePicker{{ $index }}">
            <div id="fromDateWrapper{{ $index }}" class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input id="fromDateInput{{ $index }}" type="text" ng-blur="validDate($event,$index)" is-open="openFrom{{ $index }}" ng-model="fromDate{{ $index }}" class="form-control calenderInput" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" min-date="minDate" max-date="toDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
                    <span id="fromDateButton{{ $index }}" class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " ng-click="openCalender($event,'fromDate',$index)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>      
            <div id="toDateWrapper{{ $index }}" class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group"> 
                   <input id="toDateInput{{ $index }}" type="text" ng-blur="validDate($event,$index)" is-open="openTo{{ $index }}" ng-model="toDate{{ $index }}" class="form-control calenderInput" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" min-date="fromDate{{ $index }}" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
                    <span id="toDateButton{{ $index }}" class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openCalender($event,'toDate',$index)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
   <td><button id="printReport{{ $index }}" type="button" ng-click="printReport($index)">Print Report</button></td>
</tr>
```

When hard coded, everything works. If rendered WITHOUT $index in the directives, each calendar will affect other calendars because they are all dependent on the same variables which make them show, hide, reset, etc.

Hopefully I am just doing this the wrong way or a workaround, or another solution is need soon.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible, for starters you are setting `ng-model` on a `<div></div>` when the model directive can only be used on form elements such as inputs. You are also using the `{{}}` brackets inside a directives expression which will not work.

Why don't you store your index pairs in an object and do:

```
$scope.myDiv = {};

<div ng-repeat="report in reports track by $index">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myDiv[index]" ng-show="myDiv[index]" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on $index or id, rely on object instead.
In your case - report, idk what your report is, but should be something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="validDate($event, report.fromDate)" ng-model="report.fromDate" class="form-control calenderInput" .../>
```

Comment: This solution works, as long as report.fromDate has no white spaces. Trying to apply your fix broke down when I found out the unique IDs for the dataset are 3 word phrases, like 'system traffic report'. When I name the input for custom validation and referencing, accessing functions like ng-blur still contain the whitespaces and won’t work.